# Peut-on dire « disposer de la batterie correctement » dans le sens de jeter ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Peut-on utiliser cette expression dans le sens de « jeter la batterie selon les normes » :

> disposer de la batterie correctement

Ou bien il existe une meilleure façon de le dire ?

Comment: « Disposer de la batterie correctement » n'est probablement pas idiomatique, mais en fait je ne vois même pas ce que tu veux dire (j'ai quelques hypothèses mais je ne sais pas comment choisir et je pourrais me tromper). Merci d'éditer ta question pour expliquer l'idée que tu veux exprimer.

Comment: Disposer dans le sens de recycler ou de la jeter?

Comment: Il doit y avoir confusion entre le [français « disposer »](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/disposer) et l'anglais [*dispose of*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dispose#Verb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/please+recycle.html) donne quelques idées. En bref, on peut dire « recycler », ou « éliminer » ou « jeter ».

> **Recyclez**-les lorsque possible.
>
> Pour préserver les ressources naturelles, les batteries doivent être
>   **recyclées** ou **éliminées** selon une méthode appropriée.
>
> **Jeter** les batteries conformément à la règlementation locale et les **recycler** lorsque cela est possible, mais ne pas les jeter avec les déchets ménagers.
>
> **Éliminer** les piles conformément aux dispositions nationales.

On peut dire aussi [trier](https://www.google.fr/search?q=piles+trier).

En français le verbe [disposer](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/disposer) n'a pas le sens qu'il faut ici.

Comment: « se débarasser (de)  » peut aussi être envisagé.

Comment: Pourquoi ta recherche linguee porte-t-elle sur les termes *(please) recycle* plutôt que *(please) dispose of* ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI J'ai rechercher *recycle*, parce que les normes pour se débarrasser de batteries peuvent varier d'un pays à l'autre, mais ces jours-ci ils ne se jettent plus à la poubelle. Donc ce n'est pas "*dispose of*" qu'il faut traduire, mais "*dispose of **correctly***" :-) *The correct way to 'dispose' of batteries might be to 'recycle' them.*

Comment: Aussi surprenant cela puisse paraître

Comment: @Laure Vous avez raison, mais je n'attendrais pas lire "se débarrasser" (avec deux `r`) dans une affiche officiel: cela me semble plutôt familier.

Comment: ..."selon une méthode appropriée". J'ai "adéquatement" sur un produit bon marché. Intéressant la réflexion sur la présence ou l'absence de norme et l'impact sur le choix de mots.

Answer (score 2):

"Disposer de la batterie correctement" est un anglicisme. J’opterais plutôt pour "Comment se défaire d'une batterie selon les normes légales".

Comment: Merci."Selon les normes" est meilleur. Je pensais qu'on parlait de batterie de voiture.

Comment: Bienvenue! re: je ne sais pas si l'on parle de voiture ici. Ce sont deux termes concurrents. Batterie pour n'importe quel type de pile serait un anglicisme; mais restreint à la voiture, au mobile et similaire serait valide...